# Unable to concatenate sql in pdo statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I currently have a Get varible

```
$name = $_GET['user'];
```

and I am trying to add it to my sql statement like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = ". $name;
```

and run

```
$result = $pdo -> query($sql);
```

I get an invalid column name. But that doesn't make sense because if I manually put the request like so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = 'jeff'";
```

I get the column data, just not when I enter it as a get variable. What am I doing wrong. I am relatively new to pdo.

Update:
Now I have the following:

```
$name = $_GET['user'];
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = :name";
    //run the query and save the data to the $bio variable
    $result = $pdo -> query($sql);
    $result->bindParam( ":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $result->execute();
```

but I am getting

```
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':name' at line
> 1
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `bindparam` of PDO ? http://in1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your query with the variable to work like the one without the variable, you need to put quotes around the variable, so change your query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = '$name'";
```

However, this is vulnerable to SQL injection, so what you really want is to use a placeholder, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = :name";
```

And then prepare it as you have:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
```

Next, bind the parameter:

```
$result->bindParam( ":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

And lastly, execute it:

```
$result->execute();
```

Comment: scratch that now it is saying "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':name' at line 1"

Comment: When using the `:name` placeholder instead of the actual variable, don't surround it in single quotes.

Comment: I didn't surround it in single quotes it was working but then it started spitting out that error

Comment: So you're saying that it was working, and then without making any changes it just stopped working?

Comment: yes it just stopped. I used the code you suggested using the :name as a placeholder. I just updated my code

Comment: I believe I found the issue and updated my answer accordingly, it should be `$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);` instead of `$result = $pdo->query($sql);` (I copied and pasted some of your code without proof-reading, sorry about that).

Answer (score 0):

I find this best for my taste while preventing SQL injection:

Edit: As pointed out by @YourCommonSense you should use a safe connection as per these [guidelines](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

```php
// $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

// perhaps you'll need these as well
$count = $result->num_rows;
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

/* you can also use it for multiple rows results like this
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // code here...
} */
```

BTW, if you had more parameters e.g.

```php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_user = ? AND date = ? AND location = ?'
```

where first `?` is integer and second `?` and third `?` are string/date/... you would bind them with

```php
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $id_user, $date, $location);
/*
 * i - corresponding variable has type integer
 * d - corresponding variable has type double
 * s - corresponding variable has type string
 * b - corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
 */
```

Source: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

#### EDIT:

Beware! You cannot concatenate $variables inside `bind_param`

Instead you concatenate before:

```php
$full_name = $family_name . ' ' . $given_name;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $full_name);
```

Comment: That's a correct answer *per se*, but it is rather out of line: the question is about PDO and your answer is about mysqli

Comment: Also, FYI, just a single line for the connect is [not enough](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you for your input. I never even thought about the difference. Only wanted to get rid of SQL injection attack possibilities. Edited your link to post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this .You didn't put sigle quote against variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = '". $name."'";
```

`Note`: Try to use Binding method.This is not valid way of fetching data.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/content/46/11122346/html/skippl/cake/php/retrieve_bio.php on line 24

Comment: You missed some part of the query.You can also try query like this `"SELECT * FROM uc_users WHERE user_name = '$name'"` like Nick mentioned.

Comment: I am getting "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 "

Comment: post your full query and `field` type in db.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  'uc_users'  WHERE user_name = '". $name."' ";
```